# How to return multiple fragments in PagerAdapter(not FragmentPagerAdapter)

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablayout

> PagerAdapter Class
>
> > I am building an app that has many functionalities. I created a tab layout. There are two fragments. How to return fragment in instantiateItem method. The way I did strong textin the output EmployeeAdd fragment is not showing anything. Earlier I created FragmentPagerAdapter. The code was working fine. But since FragmentPagerAdapter deprecated so I switch to PagerAdapter

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {

    @StringRes
    private static final int[] TAB_TITLES = new int[]{R.string.tab_text_1, R.string.tab_text_2};
    private final Context context;
    private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    int layouts [] = {R.layout.fragment_employee_add, R.layout.fragment_employee_delete};

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return layouts.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position){
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View one=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employee_add,container,false);
        View two=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employee_delete,container,false);
        View viewArray [] = {one, two};
        container.addView(viewArray[position]);

        switch (position){
            case 0:
                return new EmployeeAddFragment();
            case 1:
                return new EmployeeDeleteFragment();
        }
        //container.addView(one);
        return container;
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return context.getResources().getString(TAB_TITLES[position]);
    }
    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull @NotNull View view, @NonNull @NotNull Object object) {
        return view == object;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup collection, int position, Object view) {
        collection.removeView((View) view);
    }
}
```

> EmployeeAddFragment
>
> > this is my fragment. It has many editText and a button that adds all the data to database. I couldn't resolve the problem. Please help me

```
public class EmployeeAddFragment extends Fragment {

    DBHelper myDB;

    EditText substationNumber, employeeId, employeeName, password, phoneNumber, dateOfJoining, permanentOrTemporary, designation, security;
    Button addEmployee;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saveInstanceState){
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_employee_add, container, false);

        substationNumber = rootView.findViewById(R.id.substationNumber);
        employeeId = rootView.findViewById(R.id.employeeId);
        employeeName = rootView.findViewById(R.id.employeeName);
        password = rootView.findViewById(R.id.passwordEmployee);
        phoneNumber = rootView.findViewById(R.id.phoneNumber);
        dateOfJoining = rootView.findViewById(R.id.dateOfJoining);
        permanentOrTemporary = rootView.findViewById(R.id.permanentOrTemporary);
        designation = rootView.findViewById(R.id.designation);
        security = rootView.findViewById(R.id.security);
        addEmployee = rootView.findViewById(R.id.addSubstationButton);

        if(myDB == null)
            myDB = new DBHelper(getActivity());

        addEmployee.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                addEmployeeFunction();
            }

        });

        return rootView;
    }

    //function to add user to the database by admin
    private void addEmployeeFunction() {

        //Todo edit this part
        Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Employee Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        /*String getEmployeeID = employeeId.getText().toString();
        String getEmployeeName = employeeName.getText().toString();
        String getPassword = password.getText().toString();

        int lengthOfPassword = password.length();

        if(TextUtils.isEmpty(getEmployeeID) || TextUtils.isEmpty(getEmployeeName) ||TextUtils.isEmpty(getPassword) )
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Please enter all the fields.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else if(lengthOfPassword < 6)
            Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Password length must be greater than 5", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        else{
            boolean isInserted = myDB.insertDataIntoDatabase(getEmployeeID, getEmployeeName, getPassword);
            if(isInserted)
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Employee Added Successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            else
                Toast.makeText(getActivity().getApplicationContext(), "Entry failed.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            employeeId.setText("");
            employeeName.setText("");
            password.setText("");
        }*/
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can go with SmartFragmentStatePagerAdapter
https://guides.codepath.com/android/viewpager-with-fragmentpageradapter